# Tkinter window bind stops working after 'return'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I currently have an event bound to my window so that when the enter key is pressed checkPassword() is called. This works fine but when checkPassword() is called the event is still bound, therefore using the enter key to clear the error box, when leaving the entries blank, does not work as it calls itself.

```
 def logIn():
        usernameLabel = Label(frame, text = 'Username: ')
        passwordLabel = Label(frame, text = 'Password: ')
        usernameEntry = Entry(frame)
        passwordEntry = Entry(frame, show="*")
        Button1 = Button(frame, text = 'Log in', command = lambda: checkPassword(usernameEntry, passwordEntry))
        usernameLabel.pack()
        usernameEntry.pack()
        passwordLabel.pack()
        passwordEntry.pack()
        Button1.pack(side=RIGHT)
        window.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", lambda event: checkPassword(usernameEntry, passwordEntry))

    def checkPassword(usernameEntry, passwordEntry):
        username = usernameEntry.get()
        password = passwordEntry.get()
        if username == '':
            box.showerror('Error', 'Field can not be blank')
            return
        elif password == '':
            box.showerror('Error', 'Field can not be blank')
            return
        else:
            # do something

    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter.messagebox as box
    window = Tk()
    frame = Frame(window)
    logIn()
    frame.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

To get around this I tried to unbind the window event in the checkPassword function, which also works, however after returning to logIn() the window bind in logIn() no longer works? (everything else such as buttons function ok).

```
def checkPassword(usernameEntry, passwordEntry):
    window.unbind("<KeyRelease-Return>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<KeyRelease-Return>
```

Try using:

```
<Return>
```

The `release` binding is being triggered because the key press closes the dialog box, then the release triggers the binding again.